# How to get most latest modified child record for a parent record in Apex Class?

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to latest child record from a few child records under a parent.

Below is how it looks in my code,

```
set<id> caseSMSId = new set<case>();
caseSmsId = [case1.id, case2.id, case3.id];

list<smsnotification__c> smscaseId = new list<smsnotification__c>();

smscaseid = [{id=a1, lastmodifiedDate=03/13, case__c = case1.id}, {id=a2, 
            lastmodifiedDate=03/12, case__c = case1.id}, {id=a3, 
            lastmodifiedDate=03/11, case__c = case1.id},{id=a4, 
            lastmodifiedDate=03/13, case__c = case2.id},{id=a5, 
            lastmodifiedDate=03/14, case__c = case2.id}]
```

I am trying to get the latest modified sms notifications for a particular case from above list smsCaseID.

Expected Result should look like below list :

```
list<smsnotification__c> workSMS = new list<smsnotification__c>();
workSMS = [a1, a5];
```

So far, I created a map to put the records of case asa key and it's corresponding sms notifications list as value set.

```
for(case c : caseList){

            list<sms_notification__c> snList = new list<sms_notification__c>();

            for(sms_notification__c sn : smsCaseId){
                if(sn.case__c == c.id){
                    snlist.add(sn);
                }
            }
            snMap.put(c, snList);
        }
```

Here, how do I retrieve only the latest modified smsnotification from that list of case's child records?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to make use of a parent-child subquery.

As the "subquery" part of that might suggest, it's basically a query inside of a query. That means that you can add filters.

Something like

```
[SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id FROM Contacts ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
 FROM Account
 WHERE BillingState = 'CA'
]
```

would fetch only the most recently modified Contact related to the account.

In a lot of cases, a parent-child subquery can be converted into a query on the child object itself, e.g.

```
// This query for demonstration purposes only
// I would not use this over the parent-child subquery presented earlier
[SELECT Id, Account.Id, Account.Name FROM Contact ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1]
```

but in situations where you're ordering by a field, the above is largely unhelpful because you're ordering all of the child records amongst each other instead of ordering and clustering (I want to avoid the term "grouping" here, since that may lead people to using the GROUP BY clause, which would likely be even *less* useful).

Perhaps a better way to explain it is that the parent-child subquery orders *locally*, whereas a more "normal" query orders *globally*. Picking x records from each of y parents is something that requires "local" information.

You could still associate the globally ordered results to their given parent records, but that'd require more code and more work. Why do the work yourself in Apex if SOQL will do it for you at little/no extra cost?

As parting advice, the following pattern is generally a red flag

```
for(Object1 rec1 :record1List){
    for(Object2 rec2 :record2List){
        if(rec1.Field == rec2.Field){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

It wastes a lot of its time checking an equality that will be false more often than not. In most cases, it's better to create a map where the value of your target field (usually an Id) allows you to access the record with that value.

```
Map<Id, Object1> obj1Map = new Map<Id, Object1>();

for(Object1 rec1 :record1List){
    obj1Map.put(rec1.Field, rec1);
}

for(Object2 rec2 :record2List){
    Object1 relatedRecord = obj1Map.get(rec2.Field);
    // Do work
}
```

The above isn't a completely safe implementation of the idea. It's meant to get you thinking about a different approach so that you can do more research/experimentation on your own.

Comment: I am trying to use the parent child query here but the Case object and the child object are in lookup and somehow while storing it in a list I am getting variable does not exist.

I have also tried the Map way as you can see above. I am not getting the logic to implement after the Map.

This is what I have on parent child query : 
`list<case> csLst = new List<case>([select id, (select id from SMS_Notifications__r order By createdDate DESC limit 1) from case  where id IN:caseList]);

I am getting error  for `cslst.SMS_Notifications__r `, where it says SMS_Notifications__r is not valid.

Comment: ok I got that to work. Accessing it through a loop variable of Case.

`list<case> csLst = new List<case>([select id, (select id from SMS_Notifications__r order By createdDate DESC limit 1) from case  where id IN:caseList]);
            system.debug('325 --- :'+cslst);
            
            for(case c : cslst ) {

                for(sms_notification__c sn : c.SMS_Notifications__r ) {

                        system.debug('334 ---:'+sn);

                }

            }`

this is what I am doing now, does this make sense? can you help?

Comment: @apple123 This works for lookup relationships just fine. It sounds like you've left out important information from your question. You should go back and edit your question. Also, remember to give the full text of error messages verbatim (and provide the code the error is complaining about and enough context for others to make sense of that code).

Answer (score 0):

SubQuery as mentioned above should do the trick for you. I would say do something like this -  The list/Map both gives the latest updated smsnotification record per case.

```
List<id> snList = new List<id>();
Map<Id,sms_notification__c) snMap = new Map<id,sms_notification__c>();
for(Case c : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM sms_notification__r ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Case where Id IN: caseList]){
    //Not sure if u need list or map so added both
    snList.add(c.sms_notification__r);
    snMap.put(c.Id, c.sms_notification__r);
}
```